# Changing the instrumentation class in an Android Studio run configuration

Tags: android-studio

I have somewhat of a complex test setup for my Android project and it requires different test runners. I have setup my Gradle file so that it switches the test runner according to a project property. That way I can control the test runner when running tests via a Gradle script.

However, I'd love to do the same with an Android Studio run configuration. But the *Instrumentation Class* field seems to be grayed out and AS won't let me change it. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVtwc.png).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by setting up `testInstrumentationRunner` in build.gradle, e.g.

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
       ...
       testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Of course it might work or not depending on your Gradle setup - you wrote you're doing some complex things, but this might be a place to start.